# How to tell if button was not clicked in android?

Tags: android

I have a count down timer and if the user does not click this button on an even number I need to perform a certain method which will end my game. So basically if the user stops tapping I need the gameOver() method called.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GameScreen extends Activity {

    private TextView time;
    private Button start;
    private Button cancel;
    private Button gameButton;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    public static int count = 0;
    int foo = Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString());

    private View.OnClickListener btnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.start_ID :
                    start();
                    break;
                case R.id.cancel :
                    cancel();
                    break;
                case R.id.gameButton_ID :
                    gameButton();
                    break;
            }

        }


    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_ID);
        start.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        gameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gameButton_ID);
        gameButton.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);

    }

    public void start(){
        time.setText("15");
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(15 * 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millsUntilFinished){
                time.setText("" + millsUntilFinished / 1000);

                //this doesnt work and makes app crash when you hit start button
                if((gameButton.isPressed() != true) && foo  % 2 == 0){
                    gameOver();
                }
            }

            public void onFinish(){
                time.setText("Done !");
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    private void cancel(){
        if(countDownTimer != null){
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;
        }
    }

    private void gameOver(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You scored " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        count = 0;
        cancel();
    }


    private void gameButton(){

        if(foo  % 2 == 0 ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PASS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ++count;
        }

        else{
            gameOver();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't just add a boolean attribute to your activity class, set it to true when the button is clicked, check it when your scheduled thread kicks in and set it back to false if it's the case or "end your game" if it's not.

Comment: Would work but would you know how to get it to check on each even number? I thought of that but felt like there had to be an easier way.

Comment: "to check on each even number?" I didn't get this one. May you explain what are you looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry that was part of the game I was making was to tap on every other second but I thought I said that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : 
You can use a `TimerTask` that periodically verifies wether or not the Button was clicked. You do not need the **counterBTnnotclicked** variable any more.

So you can do something like this  : (Am trying to write this quickly, so  be aware of that)

```
class BtnClickIntegerHolder{

   public int counterBtnClicked = 0;
}

class BtnClicksCheckerIntegerHolder{

   public int btnClicks  = 0;
}

final BtnClickIntegerHolder btnClickCounter = new BtnClickIntegerHolder();


    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnClickCounter.counterBtnClicked = btnClickCounter.counterBtnClicked + 1;
                }
            });
         int period = 10000; // repeat every 10 secs.

           final BtnClicksCheckerIntegerHolder btnClicksHolder = new BtnClicksCheckerIntegerHolder();
btnClicksHolder.btnClicks = btnClickCounter.counterBtnClicked;

            Timer timer = new Timer();

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {

                    if(btnClickCounter.counterBtnClicked == btnClicksHolder.btnClicks ){
                        //Button was not clicked
                    }
                    else{
                        //Button was  clicked
                    }

btnClicksHolder.btnClicks = btnClickCounter.counterBtnClicked;
                }

            }, period, period);
```

Comment: How could I keep counterBtnNotClicked synced up with countDownTimer?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is take one boolean called `isClickedOnEvenNumber`. Now when you press the button when even-number set `isClickedOnEvenNumber` as

```
isClickedOnEvenNumber = true;
```

Now check on every tick check that

```
if(isClickedOnEvenNumber)
     //continue game
else
     //end game
```